# SQL Server datatable fills System.Net.Mail Body

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, azure

I'm trying to populate the Body of an email using System.Net.Mail.MailMessage() with a filled datatable. Is this possible or the wrong approach?

```
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
    da.Fill(dt);
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    mail.Body =  ?  ;
```

Comment: What is inside datatable ? Is it a single row or it has multiple rows ?

Comment: You can't assign it to DataTable. You can generate HTML representation of your DataTable as a string and assign it to this property.

Comment: Multiple rows @Mairaj.

Comment: PLease show structure of table(add in question) ?

Comment: Thats kind of what I was thinking too @Soner I just wasn't sure to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `data` from all `rows` and store it in a `string` and than assign this string to `mail.Body` like this.

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    sb.Append(dr["columnName"].ToString() + "<br />");
}
mail.Body = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible..

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
da.Fill(dt);
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
mail.Body =  dt.Table[your_table].Rows[your_row][your_coulmn].ToString()  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a project for 5 years ago, I used this way to generate `HtmlTable` and get a string from that `HtmlTable` like;

```
public static HtmlTable GenerateHtmlTableForMail(DataTable dt)
{
        HtmlTable retval = new HtmlTable();
        HtmlTableRow tr = new HtmlTableRow();
        HtmlTableCell td = new HtmlTableCell();

        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            td = new HtmlTableCell();
            td.InnerText = col.ColumnName;
            tr.Cells.Add(td);
        }
        retval.Rows.Add(tr);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            tr = new HtmlTableRow();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                td = new HtmlTableCell();
                td.InnerText = row[col].ToString();
            }
            retval.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
        return retval;
}
```

And

```
public static string GetHtmlTableString(HtmlTable table)
{
    string retval = "";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    table.RenderControl(htw);
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

In your case, you can assign your `mail.Body` property what that `GetHtmlTableString` returns.